# KeyVaultClient making a single request using GetSecretAsync via the client library generates an additional call to Key Vault

Tags: .net-core, azure-keyvault

We are using the KeyVaultClient library on an application in Service Fabric that calls a Key Vault to read various configuration data stored as secrets.  The way the code authenticates to the vault is via an AAD principal with an SSL certificate.  The code is creating a single request, but when we look at Key Vault logs, for every single request the code creates, the vault is hit twice.  The first hit generates a 401 Unauthorized and then the second request is a Success.

It seems as if the library is possibly first attempting to hit the Key Vault without the credentials in our request before proceeding with the request we create.  The second request works exactly as expected.  This seems unnecessary.  Has anyone had a similar experience?

Comment: Could you share your code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Azure Keyvault has an authentication pattern which will always **make at least one unauthenticated call to the vault**. This is because some vaults have requirements that messages to them be encrypted with HSM protected keys. This information is returned in the authentication challenge from the first unauthenticated call.

For this reason each time you send a request to a vault you haven't connected to yet in that process, the sdk first sends the request with an empty body and without an Authorization header. This will result in a 401 which will have the authentication and message protocol information.

For more details, you could refer to the similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/3065).